# Open a colorbox from a loaded page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to show a [colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) when I click on a button loaded with load().

In my current page:

```
    $("#button_loading").click(function(){
        $('#div_container').load("myurl");
    });
```

Loaded page script:

```
$("#button_opening_colorbox").on('click', function() {      
    $.colorbox({ 
        inline:true, 
        href:"#mini_div_info" }, 
        onOpen: function(){
                    $('#mini_div_info').fadeIn();
        }

    });
    alert("a");                         
});
```

I can see the alert message "a" but not the colorbox. Besides, my colorbox appears when I don't call it from a loaded page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the site's examples, it looks like you can't just pass a string. A key is required:

```
// Format:
$(selector).colorbox({key:value, key:value, key:value});
```

Here's an example passing raw HTML:

```
$.colorbox({html:"<h1>Welcome</h1>"});
```

via http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

---

There's also an extra bracket in your code.

```
href:"#mini_div_info" },
                  ----^
```